# I'm getting an error while compiling some math

Tags: amsmath, compilation-error, mathbb

While using `\include{selectors.tex}`

with a line like this:

```
Suppose $\langle x_n \rangle _{n \in \nat}$ is a rapidly converging sequence of
converges to some irrational number.
```

I'm getting this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.22 Suppose $\langle x_n \rangle _{n \in \nat
                                              }$ is a rapidly converging seq...
```

I really do not know what's wrong with it ?

Comment: Have you defined `\nat` somewhere? It's not a standard command

Comment: @JosephWright Good :-)

Comment: It is also telling you that `\nat` is the problem: the line break comes right after the command TeX did not understand.

Comment: What happens if you add the instructions `\usepackage{amssymb}` and `\providecommand{\nat}{\mathbb{N}}` in the preamble and recompile?

Comment: Off-topic: To facilitate your readers' understanding of the material, you may also want to change "sequence of converges to" to "sequence that converges to".